# Move text baseline in <li> 2 px up

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I have implemented my webpage menu by inline "li"-s of "ul". "li" has a colored border and contains "a". Now on mouse hover I need to change color of the text inside "a" and move it 2px up by not moving the li border. How can I do that?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

HTML -->

```
 <div id="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
 </div> <!-- end menu -->
```

CSSS -->

```
div#menu ul
{
list-style-type:none;
}   
div#menu li
{
margin-left:2px;
display:inline-block;

border: 1px #FFF solid;
border-top:none;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 11px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6px 11px;
}
div#menu li:hover
{
border-top:none;            
border: 1px #95d9e4 solid;
}
div#menu li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
font-size:14px;
margin:0 6px 2px 6px;
line-height:20px;

}
div#menu li a:hover
{
color:#95d9e4;
margin:0 6px 4px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Try posting your code here. The CSS selector you need is a:hover{}

Comment: Post your code into jsfiddle.net and send us the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
li:hover {
  border-top: none;
}

# Note: this is different from 'li a:hover'!
li:hover a {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle example. You're fast!

Comment: It moves up the baseline up but after that I see top border :(. Actually this <div id="menu"> should be inside the header div which should start from the most top point and have fixed height and width should be 100%. And menu div should be on the right top corner of header div.

Comment: @Karine: Let me try to understand better. Do you want _also_ want to remove the top border upon hover? If yes, then try my suggestion again (just edited).

Comment: Note that @Purmou's answer uses `li a:hover`, which is different from `li:hover a`: we need the latter.

Comment: @Purmou http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4HPmM/ does not work for latest mozilla :(. What is the problem?

Comment: Instead of text going up, borders come down in mozilla.

Comment: @Karine: Latest as in Nightly or the latest stable one?

Comment: @Purmou For Firefox 7.0.1 and for 8.0 too

Comment: Someone has any idea why http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4HPmM does not work for firefox???

Comment: @Karine: Let's try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/CdZSh/ (I've verified that it works on the latest Firefox). **Note:** I suggest that you maintain the borders and paddings as part of `<a>` so, upon `<li>` hover, the changes in borders and paddings happen simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Add bottom padding, subtract from line height:

```
div#menu li a:hover {
  color:#95d9e4;
  margin:0 6px 6px 6px;
  line-height:18px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
}
```